# The Google Admin SDK API errors out with no explanations

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk

Regarding this API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#accessing_account_information

I have been using the `Admin SDK` to retrieve login history for users in our `Google Apps` for `Business` setup. When I request individual users at a time, the request sometimes takes a few hours to process (in which the state is `PENDING`). However, when those few hours pass, I still get the login history that I need.

The problem continues as I begin requesting more users. We have around 750 users, and of those 750~ requests I made, 725 gave me an error after waiting ONE WEEK for my requests to be processed. Even worse, the ones that did not error out are still pending! Here is the response I get when I check the status of a request that errored out:

`{'status': 'ERROR', 'adminEmailAddress': '***@etsy.com', 'requestDate': '***', 'requestId': '***', 'userEmailAddress': '***@etsy.com'}`

This has got to be the flakiest and most unreliable API I have ever been unfortunate enough to work with. Requests can take anywhere from an hour to over a week to process, with no indicator of success in the mean time. Errors can also happen for no apparent reason, and no messages or explanations as to why.

Comment: This bug has been triaged to Google internally.  If you have a Google Apps for Business account, I do encourage you to contact Google Apps Support.

Comment: Thanks. We do have a Google Apps for Business account, and I've tried support. After some mailing back and forth, it seemed the only "solution" was "the API was designed this way, deal with it." I'll open up another support request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue has been resolved by the Google Engineers.  Try to run the calls again.  It shouldn't be in pending more than the "normal" expected time.  I just tried earlier, and I was able to export login info for my users.

Comment: The wait time for pending state has gone down significantly, even for large amounts of users. I am still receiving "Internal Server Errors" when I request information for most users, however.